# How to set background color of a cell depending on a DataGrid alternation index?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, triggers

I would like to change the background color of a cell depending on the alternation index of the DataGrid. My template looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
  <Label x:Name="MyLabel">foobar</Label>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" TargetName="MyLabel"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="MyLabel"/>
    </Trigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Whereas my `DataGrid` has set the property:

```
   <DataGrid AlternationCount="2"> ... </DataGrid>
```

The blue background works, but all cells have a blue background and no cell a red background. What is missing here?

Comment: is this a celltemplate?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use DataTrigger instead of Triggers

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
  <Label x:Name="MyLabel">foobar</Label>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="0">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" TargetName="MyLabel"/>
    </DataTrigger >
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="1">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="MyLabel"/>
    </DataTrigger >
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```